# MapR HBase truncate change permission

Tags: hbase, mapr

I have an HBase table with permission of 777. Whenever I truncate this table (`truncate` command on the table), the table permission is changed to r--------. Do you know why?

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried it in M7 but i am not able to reproduce this issue. it is might be happening because it internally recreate the directory and the default permission for directory is set to 400.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in M7, the HBase table permission can only be changed using Access Control Expression (ACE)